# Selected column in a pandas dataframe to newline delimited json

Tags: python, json

df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[123,465,978,505,567], "feature":[1.1,1.2,1.2,6.7,8.9]})

I try to only save a json file just for the `id` column. However, it seems that there is no column selection in the `to_json` function.

My ideal result is like

```
{"id":123}
{"id":465}
{"id":978}
{"id":505}
{"id":567}
```

I've tried
method 1: `df.to_json("temp.json", orient="records", lines=True)`

result 1:

```
{"id":123,"feature":1.1}
{"id":465,"feature":1.2}
{"id":978,"feature":1.2}
{"id":505,"feature":6.7}
{"id":567,"feature":8.9}
```

method 2: `df['id'].to_json("temp.json", orient="records", lines=True)`

result 2:

```
123
465
978
505
567
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `df[["id"]]`:

```py
df[["id"]].to_json("temp.json", orient="records", lines=True)
```

saves `temp.json`:

```json
{"id":123}
{"id":465}
{"id":978}
{"id":505}
{"id":567}
```

Comment: It works. Got it! I still need to make it a dataframe!